# How do I say "that induces anxiety" in Italian?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

"Anxiogenic" in English means "something/someone that creates/induces/provokes anxiety".

Is there an equivalent in Italian? I can't find "ansiogenico" in Italian dictionaries.

I can find "ansiogeno" but this seems to mean "someone who has anxiety", rather than "something that creates/induces anxiety".

Comment: Why do you think "ansiogeno" refers to a person who has anxiety? I've never seen this usage anywhere...

Comment: You are perhaps mixing up _ansiogeno_ with _ansioso_, the latter one meaning indeed “who experiences anxiety”.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word you found [**ansiogeno**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ansiogeno/), according to Treccani's dictionary

> ansiògeno agg. [comp. di ansia e -geno]. – In psicologia e
> psichiatria, che genera ansia: *situazione ansiogena*.

exactly means:

> In psychology and psychiatry, something that generates anxiety:
> *anxiogen situation*.

You can also apply the term to a situation or also to a person who generates anxiety on itself.

Comment: How do I apply it to a person that generates anxiety in other people, or to a population in general?

Comment: @user180940 you can use it as any other adjective: "_Maria è una persona **ansiogena**_" =  "Maria is an anxiogenic person", "_non sopporto Mario per più di dieci minuti, è così **ansiogeno**!_" = "I cannot stand Mario for longer than ten minutes, he is so anxiogenic!"

Comment: Even though "ansiogeno" is the correct word, in spoken Italian it isn't used as often: "che ti mette ansia" ("who gives you anxiety") instead is much more likely to be used. "Maria è una persona che ti mette ansia" .

Comment: I agree, "ansiogeno" is mainly used as a specialized/technical terms in the fields of psychology and psychiatry and sometimes is (mis)used during conversations with people with whom you have a strong familiarity, if you want to suggest s/he is being a pain in the... neck (think of a kid continuously asking "are we there, yet?", during a car trip or of someone questioning a decision you took by asking about all possible things which could go wrong).

Comment: It might be a matter of mileu: I am quite used to *ansiogeno* used in colloquial speech (sometimes with the added humorous effect of using a highly specialized word in an informal context).